# ParametricPlot3D Question

Tags: plotting

When I graph:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  If[11*Cos[t] <= 5, 
    {9*Cos[s]*Sin[t], 10*Sin[s]*Sin[t], 
    11*Cos[t]}, Null], 
{s, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, Pi}]
```

I get

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug5HR.gif]

but I want to get:

[image]

Why does my code generate those spike and etches on top of the partially cut ellipsoid, instead of giving a smooth top like the second picture?

Comment: Hi "user9197"! I edited your question a bit - if you want to see how, click on the "edit/edited" links above.

Comment: Thank You, I wasn't able to add pictures since I did not have enough reputation.

Comment: How did you get 2nd graph?

Comment: I used ContourPlot3D, but I want to make the graph using a parametric setting.

Answer (score 7):

### Better solution

Actually, you don't need a different parametrization as I suggest below. I haven't really looked at your formula before which I should have done. The probably best solution is to transform your condition into explicit values for `t` like this:

```
Reduce[11*Cos[t] <= 5 && 0 <= t <= Pi, t]

(* ArcCos[5/11] <= t <= Pi *)
```

And now you remove your if condition and adjust your time interval

```
ParametricPlot3D[{9*Cos[s]*Sin[t], 10*Sin[s]*Sin[t], 11*Cos[t]}, 
 {s, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, ArcCos[5/11], Pi}]
```

That's far easier.

### Quick Hack

`ParametricPlot3D` expects 3d point for all input values of `s` and `t`. What you do by returning `Null` is kind of *rude* and most likely confuses the algorithm which tries to construct a polygon surface.

I would really recommend that you transform your expression into a better parameterization, but for a quick hack it seems sufficient to **not** return `Null` but the point on the ring at `z=5`.

```
expr = {9*Cos[s]*Sin[t], 10*Sin[s]*Sin[t], 11*Cos[t]}; 
sol = Last@Solve[11*Cos[t] == 5, t];
With[{surf = expr, ring = expr /. sol},
 ParametricPlot3D[
  If[11*Cos[t] <= 5, surf, ring], {s, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, Pi}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: THANKS. Can you please recommend how transform this into a better parametrization.

Comment: @user9197 Please see my update. Sorry, you parametrization is fine, but what you can do is, you can calculate explicit settings for your time interval which fulfill the if if condition you are using.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with `RegionFunction`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{9*Cos[s]*Sin[t], 10*Sin[s]*Sin[t], 11*Cos[t]}, 
 {s, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, Pi}, RegionFunction -> (11 Cos[#5] <= 5 &)]
```

[image]

Comment: What does #5 mean.